# In php how to resolve setlocale conflict

Tags: php, locale

In a php plugin I wrote this function :

```
function is_number( $nbr ){
    $locale= get_locale();
    setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, $locale );
    return ( is_numeric( $nbr ) || is_float( $nbr ) );
}
```

...with a namespace of course.

The problem is that function generates a css bug because in an other block of code, there is a php function to generate the opacity float and and create a rbga as string like `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` thanks to this function :

```
function stylesheet_get_opacity( $opacity = 0 ) {
    $opacity = ($opacity > 0) ? $opacity/100 : 0;
    return $opacity;
}
```

So `$opacity` should be all the time like `0.5` and not with coma. But if my function will set local and you are in France for example, if the input `$opacity` is equal to `50`, the output will be `0,5` and not `0.5` which will break the css at the end.

So, how can I do to resolve this without change `stylesheet_get_opacity` which is not from my code ?

Maybe, should I reset `setLocale` after the numeric checking, but how to do this ?

Something like that :

```
function is_number( $nbr ){
    $locale= get_locale();
    setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, $locale );
    $output = ( is_numeric( $nbr ) || is_float( $nbr ) );
    //Here reset setlocale
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

In my case, the `NULL` affect the locale setting and reset it. `0` value did not work.

So this is the complete solution :

```
function is_number( $nbr ){
    $locale= get_locale();
    setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, $locale );
    $output = ( is_numeric( $nbr ) || is_float( $nbr ) );
    setlocale( LC_NUMERIC, NULL );
    return $output;
}
```